# Ordering citations in text with natbib

Tags: citing, natbib, multiple-citations

I want my natbib citations in the compiled PDF document to look like this:

> (Yellow 2010, p. 111, see also Brown 2011, Red 2012)

I have really struggled to use the \citep commands to get to that result. (E.g., it orders citations alphabetically, and i cannot get the "p. 111, see also" to appear at the right place).

Does anyone know how I can get to the desired format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Do not forget to add the used or a part of it bib file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you combine a `\citetext` instruction with a couple of `\citealt` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% create a sample bib file "on the fly":    
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{y:2010, author={Yellow},title={X},year=2010}
@misc{b:2011, author={Brown}, title={Y},year=2011}
@misc{r:2012, author={Red},   title={Z},year=2012}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib. style
\setcitestyle{citesep={,}} % default separator between citations: ';'

\begin{document}
\citetext{\citealt[p.~111]{y:2010}; see also \citealt{b:2011,r:2012}}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```